# A question about cyclomatic complexity

Tags: testing, cyclomatic-complexity

Assume the flow graph of a function is below (sorry I have forgotten the code of the function):[image]

And when I try to calculate the cyclomatic complexity:

When I use the edge and node to calculate it, `V(G)= 9 - 8 + 2 = 3`; when I use the branch node to calculate it, `V(G) = 3 + 1 = 4`. However, when I try to find the independent paths, I think I can find 4 paths:

```
Path 1: 1 -> 2 -> 6 -> 7
Path 2: 1 -> 2 -> 6 -> 8
Path 3: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 5 -> 2 -> ...
Path 4: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 2 -> ...
```

And I wonder which one is correct and what is my mistake? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The simplified formulas don't work because you have multiple exit points (states 7 and 8). There are more complete formulas, or you can introduce an exit state E plus the edges 7→E, 8→E.

Comment: @amon I think it should be 7->E, 8->E